# Phonegap build cli 5.2.0 - camera works either in android or ios but not in both

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I have camera function in ionic application and I am using phonegap build to publish app for ios and android.

My problem is - when I upload code from windows and build app for android and ios on phonegap, camera only works in android but not in ios. And when I upload code from mac and build app for android and ios on phonegap, camera only works in ios but not in android. On camera function, no error thrown.

When I debugged app on android using adb plugin, on app start it shows message "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds" in console.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about posting your code?

Comment: which code you need?

Comment: the code you use that doesn't work. Anyway, after reading your question again it doesn't make much sense, you say that uploading the same code from a windows machine makes it work only on android and uploading the same code from a mac machine makes it work only on iOS? is the exact same code?

Comment: yes, the same code. When I tested the app uploaded via mac and debugged the code with android device in adb plugin I found that it shows message "device ready event not fired after 5 seconds" and the same code is working in iphone. Another message it shows is related to some cordova event. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is what I did. First I have developed app for android on windows machine. Then to debug and test the the same code in iphone, I have copied the code from windows to mac and added ios platform, configure the certificate, tested the app in device via xcode. When I tested the app via xcode in debug mode, cordova deviceready event fires and camera plugin is working fine. But when I upload the 'www' folder on phonegpa build and build the app for ios and android, the deviceready event fires in iphone and not in the android. It's wired but true.